# Mask for Ripple effect drawable

Tags: android, selector, ripple

I have used ripple effect on a view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@android:color/black">

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="?android:colorAccent" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="@android:color/white" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

Problem is when I click on button, borders effected as well which I specified with 2dp width as stroke.

To fix the problem I used `android:id="@android:id/mask"` for the first item in ripple drawable as specified in [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/RippleDrawable.html). But it just remove the color of item from button.

So then how can I mask ripple effect for specific item and not all child layers?

I tried it in on Android with Lolipop version as well as Marshmallow.

Comment: you set `width` only on the second `stroke`.

Comment: I tried that and it did not work. It actually effect the borders even if I set it for 1st item.

Comment: Maybe you can try to use a container, like **LinearLayout**, and then set paddings of the container.

Comment: I have tried that also. Have you tried yourself?